# Underline nav links, attach to bottom of div and limit width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar and I want to underline the links on hover. The issue is that the underline (using border-bottom) is sitting directly under the li element and I want to attach it to the bottom of the grandparent div [the nav in the below example].
Additionally, I want to limit the width of this underline to the width of the text itself, not the entire element it's underlining.

```
<nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand header-title" href="#/home">Title!</a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-links">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav my-nav" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#/link1">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#/link2">Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
.my-nav > li:hover {
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid white;
}
```

See jsfiddle for full example, http://jsfiddle.net/8kzpjeyv/1/embedded/result/ (make sure your viewport is wide enough so menu isn't collapsed)

1. Want to make the underline at the very bottom of the blue bar so it looks like it's part of the white body
2. Want to limit the width of the underline to the exact width of the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use padding-bottom:

```
.my-nav > li:hover {
    padding-bottom: .2em;
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid white;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kzpjeyv/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: You rock thanks! Don't know why I didn't try that before :-\ Any hints on limiting the width? Only method I found out so far is using <hr> or :after, which I wasn't able to make work for this application.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get you!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8kzpjeyv/3/

```
.my-nav a{
      padding-left:0!important; 
      padding-right:0!important
}
```